# Custom Joomla profile plugin registered user database table update issues

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a custom extension that uses the Joomla profile plugin and extends it to provide additional fields to the user profile in the administrator panel and in the registered area on the front end of the website. The fields are set to display to admins-only, be disabled, be optional or be required. When they are set to admin-only, they do not show on the front end of the website in the "edit your profile" form. The plugin handles the UPDATE command for all fields with no issues in the administrator panel, but when the UPDATE command is triggered by a user updating their profile on the front end, all of the admin-only fields are overwritten with empty values. All of the other fields, whether they are optional or required are successfully saved or maintained in the form. I have included the custom profile plugin's PHP code below.

```
<?php
/**
* @package     Joomla.Plugin
* @subpackage  User.profile
*
* @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
* @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
*/

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

/**
* An example custom profile plugin.
*
* @since  1.6
*/
class PlgUserKiduka extends JPlugin
{

/**
 * Load the language file on instantiation.
 *
 * @var    boolean
 * @since  3.1
 */
protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param   object  &$subject  The object to observe
 * @param   array   $config    An array that holds the plugin configuration
 *
 * @since   1.5
 */
public function __construct(& $subject, $config)
{
    parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    JFormHelper::addFieldPath(__DIR__ . '/fields');
}

/**
 * Runs on content preparation
 *
 * @param   string  $context  The context for the data
 * @param   object  $data     An object containing the data for the form.
 *
 * @return  boolean
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data)
{
    // No need to display the context variable as a heading on the registration page
    // echo '<h1>'.$context.'</h1>';
    // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
    if (!in_array($context, array('com_users.profile', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.registration', 'com_admin.profile')))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (is_object($data))
    {
        $userId = isset($data->id) ? $data->id : 0;

        if ($userId > 0)
        {
            // Load the profile data from the database.
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $db->setQuery(
                'SELECT * FROM #__kiduka_accounts WHERE user_id = ' . $userId
            );
            $data->kiduka = $db->loadObject();
        }
    }

    return true;
}


/**
 * adds additional fields to the user editing form
 *
 * @param   JForm  $form  The form to be altered.
 * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
 *
 * @return  boolean
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{

    if (!($form instanceof JForm))
    {
        $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');

        return false;
    }

    // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
    $name = $form->getName();

    if (!in_array($name, array('com_admin.profile', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.profile', 'com_users.registration')))
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach(JFactory::getUser()->get('groups') as $group){
        if(in_array($group, $this->params->get('usergroup'))){
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Add the registration fields to the form.
    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/profiles');
    $form->loadFile('profile', false);

    $fields = array(
        'firechief',
        'title',
        'membership_no',
        'organization',
        'organizationtype',
        'membertype',
        'afcaregion',
        'municipalcode',
        'membershipyear',
        'address1',
        'address2',
        'city',
        'province',
        'postalcode',
        'country',
        'businessphone',
        'homephone',
        'cellphone',
        'fax',
        'notes',
        'gstexempt',
        'billorganization',
        'billaddress1',
        'billaddress2',
        'billcity',
        'billprovince',
        'billpostalcode',
        'billcountry'
    );

    // Change fields description when displayed in front-end or back-end profile editing
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        // Case using the users manager in admin
        if ($name == 'com_users.user')
        {
            // Toggle whether the field is required.
            if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0 || $this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) == -1)
            {
                $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'kiduka');
            }
            else
            {
                $form->removeField($field, 'kiduka');
            }
        }
        // Case registration
        elseif ($name == 'com_users.registration')
        {
            // Toggle whether the field is required.
            if ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field, 1) > 0)
            {
                $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'kiduka');
            }
            else
            {
                $form->removeField($field, 'kiduka');
            }
        }
        // Case profile in site or admin
        elseif ($name == 'com_users.profile' || $name == 'com_admin.profile')
        {
            // Toggle whether the field is required.
            if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0)
            {
                $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'kiduka');
            }
            else
            {
                $form->removeField($field, 'kiduka');
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * saves user profile data
 *
 * @param   array    $data    entered user data
 * @param   boolean  $isNew   true if this is a new user
 * @param   boolean  $result  true if saving the user worked
 * @param   string   $error   error message
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error)
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $modified_by = $user->get('id');
    $userId = JArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

    $datenow = JFactory::getDate();
    $modified = $datenow->toSql();

    $fields = array(
                // 'membership_no',
                'title',
                'firechief',
                'organization',
                'address1',
                'address2',
                'city',
                'province',
                'postalcode',
                'country',
                'businessphone',
                'homephone',
                'cellphone',
                'fax',
                'organizationtype',
                'membertype',
                'billorganization',
                'billaddress1',
                'billaddress2',
                'billcity',
                'billprovince',
                'billpostalcode',
                'billcountry',
                'afcaregion',
                'gstexempt',
                'notes',
                'municipalcode',
                'membershipyear'
            );

    if($isNew){
        $query = 'INSERT INTO #__kiduka_accounts VALUES(NULL, '.$userId.', "", '.$userId.', '.$userId;
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $query .= ', "'.$data['kiduka'][$field].'"';
        }
        $query .= ')';
    }else{
        $query  = 'UPDATE #__kiduka_accounts SET ';
        $query .= 'modified = "'.$modified.'", ';
        $query .= 'modified_by = "'.$modified_by.'", ';
        $query .= 'membership_no = "'.$userId.'", ';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++){
            $query .= $fields[$i] . ' = "'.$data['kiduka'][$fields[$i]].'"';
            if($i < count($fields) - 1){
                $query .= ', ';
            }

        }
        $query .= ' WHERE user_id = "'.$userId.'"';
    }

    // var_dump($data);
    // die();

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();

    // var_dump($query);
    // die();

    return true;
}

public function onUserAfterDelete($user, $success, $msg)
{
    if (!$success)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $userId = JArrayHelper::getValue($user, 'id', 0, 'int');

    if ($userId)
    {
        try
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $db->setQuery(
                'DELETE FROM #__kiduka_accounts WHERE user_id = ' . $userId);

            $db->execute();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->_subject->setError($e->getMessage());

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the admin only fields to type hidden when in the front end.

Comment: @Elin The admin-only fields are not displayed on the front end user profile edit form, so they are already hidden. This is done with the _if switches_ in the PHP profile file.

Comment: @Elin

XML field example:

`<field name="profile-require_title" type="list" description="COM_KIDUKA_FORM_LBL_USER_TITLE" label="COM_KIDUKA_FORM_LBL_USER_TITLE"> 
    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
    <option value="-1">PLG_USER_PROFILE_KIDUKA_ADMIN_ONLY</option>
</field>`

Comment: There is a difference between just "not displaying" and making the type  hidden using `setFieldAttribute` .  But you solved it another way which is also fine.

Comment: @Elin The admin-only fields are not being rendered at all on the front end edit profile page. They are not rendering as hidden with CSS or set to input type of hidden, so the code seems to working correctly for that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

@Elin I have figured it out. It was suggested on the Joomla forum to use two $fields arrays, one for the front-end profile form and another with all of the fields for the administrator user manager profile form. I have included the PHP code for the onUserAfterSave function below. The **if($app->isSite())** if/else shows the limited fields on the front-end profile form and the full list of fields on the administrator profile form.

```
public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error)
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $modified_by = $user->get('id');
    $userId = JArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

    $datenow = JFactory::getDate();
    $modified = $datenow->toSql();

    if($app->isSite())
    {
        $fields = array(
            'address1',
            'address2',
            'city',
            'province',
            'postalcode',
            'country',
            'businessphone',
            'homephone',
            'cellphone',
            'fax'
        );  
    }
    else
    {
        $fields = array(
            'firechief',
            'title',
            'organization',
            'organizationtype',
            'membertype',
            'afcaregion',
            'municipalcode',
            'membershipyear',
            'address1',
            'address2',
            'city',
            'province',
            'postalcode',
            'country',
            'businessphone',
            'homephone',
            'cellphone',
            'fax',
            'notes',
            'gstexempt',
            'billorganization',
            'billaddress1',
            'billaddress2',
            'billcity',
            'billprovince',
            'billpostalcode',
            'billcountry'
        );
    }

    if($isNew)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = 'INSERT INTO #__kiduka_accounts VALUES(NULL, '.$userId.', "", '.$userId.', '.$userId;
        foreach($fields as $field)
        {
            $query .= ', "'.$data['kiduka'][$field].'"';
        }
        $query .= ')';
    }
    else
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query .= 'UPDATE #__kiduka_accounts SET ';
        $query .= 'modified = "'.$modified.'", ';
        $query .= 'modified_by = "'.$modified_by.'", ';
        $query .= 'membership_no = "'.$userId.'", ';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++)
        {
            $query .= $fields[$i] . ' = "'.$data['kiduka'][$fields[$i]].'"';
            if($i < count($fields) - 1)
            {
                $query .= ', ';
            }

        }
        $query .= ' WHERE user_id = "'.$userId.'"';
    }

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();

    return true;
}
```